# regarding wearing hijab at work

Tags: hijab

I would like to know if hijab is not allowed in work and being rumored by non muslims.Should I have to quit my job however it was difficult to get this kind of job?

Comment: Can you expand on which country you live in and what type of work it is?  There can be safety reasons for forbidding it (e.g., it can get caught in machinery) and it may not be part of the uniform.  Many people worldwide wear hijab at work (e.g. me right now).  Personally, I wouldn't be quitting a job even if it were banned at work.

Comment: is hijab means niqab?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other option, keep your job until you find new one. Just take any job even if it's less pay or you don't like it, as long as you can wear hijab. I apply to any job and during interview I will attend with hijab so the employer knows right away my religion. Allah SWT said we are created into toil and struggle. This dunya is temporary, any struggle we have here is also temporary.